# How to find how many IO bytes a linux process has read?

Tags: linux

[Cross posted to Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/205249/how-to-find-how-many-io-bytes-a-linux-process-has-read)

Similar to the "IO Read Bytes" column in Windows Task Manager.

Comment: there is an [answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/428/how-do-i-go-about-tracking-down-io-usage-in-linux-and-other-nix-os) on **Unix.SE**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check [/proc/<pid>/io](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt#1305).

Or try [iotop](http://guichaz.free.fr/iotop/).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `atop`.